# null object reference - Music Player

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on a music player, but I keep on getting this error whenever I try to play a song

LogCat:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.musicapp.android.musicapp.PlayingScreen.playSongs(PlayingScreen.java:119)
```

Code:

```
public void playSongs() {
    if(PlayingScreen_List != null){
        uri = Uri.parse(PlayingScreen_List.get(position).getPath());
    }

    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    } else {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(uri),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
119    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

AND no, my uri is not null.....I did a TOAST and it showed me the path for every song I clicked on.....WELPP? :)

"PlayingScreen_List" is not null I did a toast...it looks like this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU1jf.jpg

Comment: It says `mediaPlayer` is null. So it looks like `MediaPlayer.create` is returning null.

Comment: Hello! I just did a toast of the "PlayingScreen_List" array, and it's not empty at all.

Comment: No, the `mediaPlayer` is null.

Comment: I posted a screenshot.....it's at the bottom, can you take a look at it.

Comment: You are right, it is null. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)

> Returns
> MediaPlayer   a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your `PlayingScreen_List`?

If

```
if(PlayingScreen_List != null){
    uri = Uri.parse(PlayingScreen_List.get(position).getPath());
}
```

is giving you null or not being called that could be causing an error when you use

`mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);`

Comment: Hello! I just did a toast of the "PlayingScreen_List" array, and it's not empty at all.

Comment: yes, the media player is null but "PlayingScreen_List" isn't. How do I fix that?

Comment: Hmm at this point I would check that the media you're trying to play is all good.

Comment: It seems that  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri); is returning null which could mean the media is no good and the creation of the object failed.